# Passing functions between python scripts with parameters

Tags: python, scripting, python-requests

I'm trying to pass parameters between python scripts where one is a GUI collecting information for a login screen and the other is the database adding and searching for the information.

[image: Code without Syntax error]

then in the database code I have:
[image: Database code]

and when i add the parameters into the function this happens:
[image: Syntax Error?]

i'm not sure how else I'm supposed to call this function.

Any ideas thanks.

Comment: just import DBRegister

Comment: please can you copy and paste the code into your answer. pictures really really dont help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to import the function, then you can call the function.

```
from Database import DBRegister
```

Then you can call the function as normal.

```
DBRegister(username, FirstName, Surname, EmployeeNumber, password)
```

or assign it to a variable:

```
dbregister = DBRegister(username, FirstName, Surname, EmployeeNumber, password)
```

It is also standard practice to include imports at the top of the file but it is not necessary..  It just stops imports getting lost inside the codebase.

UPDATE:

If you also need the cursor to insert data into the database then you will need to either import the whole file:

Note: This will run any functions that are executed in the file.

```
import Database
```

or you will have to create a new cursor inside the file you are importing into..

Please have a read of the python documentation on importing..

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: But because of the function parameters being within a function already, when i call the function in the second script it runs but no data is inputted into the database?

Comment: Thank you, managed to get it to work using your information and that of the python documentation.